# How to set initial value of input in scoped-slot?

Tags: vue.js

`index.php`

```html
    <input
        slot-scope="{ ex }"
        v-model="ex.param"
        value="something" /> <!-- Not Working -->
```

`index.vue`

```html
    <template>
        <slot :ex="ex"></slot>
    </template>
    
    <script>
        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    ex: {}
                }
            },
        }
    </script>
```

When I type something in the input above the `ex.param` will be set in vue, but when I set the value to 'something' by value attribute it doesn't change it.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`v-model` will ignore the initial `value`, `checked`, or `selected` attributes found on any form elements. **It will always treat the Vue instance data as the source of truth**. You should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side, inside the `data` option of your component.*

[...docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

The fact you are using scoped-slot here is absolutely irrelevant...

Only way is to somehow initialize the value of `ex.param` data. One option is to use prop

```html
<template>
    <slot :ex="ex"></slot>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['initValue']
        data() {
            return {
                ex: {
                  param: this.initValue
                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```